# Cordova hook to change the app name for iOS and Android

Tags: cordova

I could not manage to have a space in the app name when generating the iOS target. Overriding the app name in the manifest (android) and in resources (ios) was fine, but changes are lost as soon as I rebuild the app (as it copies again the app name from config.xml).

I was thinking of creating a hook for that. Such hook would put the proper app name value for ios and android. Are there any sample hook that does such thing and is "before_compile" the proper timing for that?

Comment: Are you building and exporting the IPAs / APKs using the native SDKs or just the command line?

Comment: I'm using the various "cordova build" commands and my goal is not to have any hand modification to re-do each time

Comment: about where to put the hook, for things like this I use after_prepare but I don't think there's much difference between after prepare and before compile?

Answer (score 7):

I created a hook to do exactly this. You can take a look at the [github repo](https://github.com/blakgeek/cordova-plugin-app-name).

The plugin takes the display name as a variable when you add it and then updates the iOS plist on install and adds an after_prepare hook that sets app_name for Android so you don't run into the issue of your change being overwritten.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-name --variable APP_NAME="My Super Cool App" --save
```

Comment: I cannot find the --variable anywhere in the cordova cli documentation. Could you explain me how it works ?

Comment: but how to use this plugin in the online service 'cordova build'? the '--variable' part?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed Cordova project names usually don't play nice when there are any spaces or special characters in the names.  I usually just have a simple project name, then override the app's display names inside the native projects.

I build my apps from the command line, as my build process is wired through jenkins.

I'm not so sure about native Cordova hooks, but on iOS, you just need to modify the "App Name".  You can do this by going to this file here

```
CORDOVA_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/platforms/ios/cordova/build.xcconfig
```

and adding the following line to the end of the file.

```
PRODUCT_NAME = My Crazy App Name With Spaces And Character !?
```

Now when you run the

```
cordova compile ios --release
```

the app will display the PRODUCT_NAME specified above, instead of the cordova project's name.

Android is a bit more complicated which requires modification of a couple of xml files.

I will update this answer in a little bit with the android solution.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question I was able for Android to create a script (that I created in dart as I am more comfortable with) using the `after_prepare` hook that simply modify the string `"app_name"` in `platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml`. Calling `cordova prepare android` properly fix the app name.

For iOS i changed the name in XCode (in xxxx-Info.plist, Bundle Display Name) and it seems that calling again `cordova prepare ios` does not override it